# Differentiate between an initial and successive call to a recursive function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

My broad question is what's the simplest way to differentiate between an initial and successive call to a recursive function in JavaScript.

Lemme give an example...

Let's say I want the following function to return false if the string passed to the function in the initial call is empty. Is there a way to do this without adding in another parameter to the function?

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
   if (str.length <= 1) {
     return true;
   }
   if (str.charAt(0) !== str.charAt(str.length -1)) {
     return false;
   }
   return isPalindrome(str.substr(1, str.length - 2));
}

isPalindrome('') // returns true, but I want this to return false
```

Btw, I know the above function could be written more simply as:

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
  return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

But I'm reframing it as a recursive function to get at the broader question here...

Comment: Pass in a second arg only on initial call

Comment: You could inspect stack trace with `arguments.callee` hack, but... better just add some param.

Comment: @Rooster—I think it would be better to pass a second argument on subsequent calls (which might be a counter to say how deep the recursion is), not the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to distinguish different calls - the result of the function should not depend on side effects and definitely not on the call stack.

Instead, use a second function that does a little different thing:

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
   return str.length <= 1 ||
     str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(str.length-1) && isPalindrome(str.slice(1, -1));
}
function isNonEmptyPalindrome(str) {
   return str.length > 0 && isPalindrome(str);
}
```

Comment: Yes, slices and shortcutting too!

Comment: +1 for some great shortcuts. But for a real palindrome, punctuation should be removed first and all letters capitalised or lower–cased.

Comment: @RobG: OP didn't do it in his code, so you rather should make this suggestion to him :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a nested function, even with the same name:

```
function isPalindrome(str) {

  // The code out here is for the initial call:
  if (str === '')
    return false;

  // Then do the recursive call
  return function isPalindrome(str) {
    // within this scope, isPalindrome refers to this function

    if (str.length <= 1) {
      return true;
    }
    if (str.charAt(0) !== str.charAt(str.length -1)) {
      return false;
    }
    return isPalindrome(str.substr(1, str.length - 2));
  }(str); // call this function immediately

}
```

For a general form:

```
function name(arg) {

    // Setup code before initial call
    //////////////////////////////

    var retVal = function name(arg) {
      // recursive routine code
    }(arg);

    // Cleanup code after recursion completes
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    return retVal;
}
```

[Demo using factorial](http://jsfiddle.net/69d3B/)

Comment: This will work only for the first call. And it is asked about first call in the stack.

Comment: @kirilloid This will once per time that isPalindrome is called, except the times it is being called recursively from itself.

Comment: Using the same name only leads to ambiguity. Don't do this.

Comment: @Bergi It's not ambiguous. It is just scoping, like having a local variable with the same name as a member variable in a class method in another language.

Comment: @Bergi It's useful if you already call that function from multiple places in your code and need to hook into that to add some special case or setup code. You could rename the inner function, but this is more clear to me.

Comment: Yes, renaming the inner function would definitely make it more clear. While the rules of scoping make it easy to figure out what happens, it's still less readable. Using different names for functions with different purposes makes it more maintainable…

Comment: @Paulpro—named function expressions are recommended against by many for the reasons outlined in [*Named function expressions demystified*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs). The answer can be refactored to be a function declaration and call, there is no need for a named expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as Bergi's answer but with the helper function declared inside *isPalindrome* so that it isn't used elsewhere.

A better example for a palindrome is that all punctuation should be removed and letters made all upper or lower case (so that comparisons are not case sensitive), but only on the first call. After that, it's a simple matter of comparing characters.

The length == zero part is also only handled once, the function isn't called recursively if there are no characters left to compare.

The following does initial processing, then calls an inner function.

A function declaration is used instead of a named function expression as the latter have [undesirable side effects in IE](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs).

```
  function isPalindrome(s) {

    // Initial processing only on first call
    // remove all punctuation
    s = s.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig,'').toLowerCase();

    return s.length == 0? false : doCheck(s);

    function doCheck(s) {

      if (s.length > 1) {

        if (s.substr(0,1) == s.substr(s.length - 1, 1)) {
          s = s.substr(1, s.length - 2);
          return s.length? doCheck(s) : true;

        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  console.log(isPalindrome("Madam I'm Adam"));  // true
  console.log(isPalindrome("Madam I'm Addam")); // false
```

Comment: You must be using a different definition of a palindrome than the OP. According to the definition I'm used to "b?/.!a!./?b", "madam", and "kayak" are examples of palindromes, but "Madam I'm Adam" and "Kayak" are not.

Comment: @Paulpro—you may be thinking of mirrored palindromes, which is one type of palindrome, but generally the definition is broader, e.g. see the [Palindrome List](http://www.palindromelist.net/), also [Palindrome Varieties](http://www.fun-with-words.com/palin_explain.html). I thought the OP was just using it as an example of having different processing for the first execution of a function that is called recursively.